# Visual Studio removes whitespace after closing tag

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, resharper

I have the problem that Visual Studio (or Resharper) removes whitespace after the  tag when I use the formatting shortcut ctrl + k + d.

Example - before using the formatting shortcut:

```
<p>Sample text <b><span class="sometext"></span></b> fooo</p>
```

Example - after using the formatting shortcut:

```
<p>Sample text <b><span class="sometext"></span></b>fooo</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ctrl+K+D runs Visual Studio formatter. To use ReSharper one, use Ctrl+E+C. But please note, that in HTML it can only fix indents for you - other spaces or new lines would stay intact.

P.S. One more shortcut for reformatting is Ctrl+E+F. First time when you invoke it you select profile (choose Reformat only and turn on using this profile by default for silent cleanup). Next time when you press Ctrl+E+F it would just silently reformat you code, without dialog.